# Sample code and API for UCP(EMI) protocol

Tags: ucp

I wanted to use UCP(EMI)protocol, can anybody help me how to use it. Please provide me a UCP(EMI)protocol APi in C/C++ for the same.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the Specification for using UCP Protocol for sending SMS

on the Internetpage: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Computer_Protocol
you can download the latest Specification:

http://www.vodafone.de/downloadarea/EmiSpec_43d.pdf

Well here is an Example about using this Protocol:

Login example of the SMSC
"STX"02/00058/O/60/"insert Short-ID"/6/5/1/"Encrypted Passwort"//0100////39//F5"ETX"

Positive Answer of SMSC System is
"STX"02/00019/R/60/A//6F"ETX"

Write a SMS:
"STX"03/00085/O/51/XXXXXXXXXX/SSSSS//1//7///////1408121759//////3//54657374/////////////36"ETX"

explaination:
"Start of Message
STX

"Head Message"
"Transactionnumber"/"messageLength"/"Operation"/"OperationType"

"Body Message"
/"Recipient"/"Short-ID"//"Notification Request"//"NotificationType"///////"Timestamp"//////"Type of Message"//"encrypted TextMessage"////////////"Checksum"

"End of Message"
ETX

For more Information see please Specification Paper!